# Disable *.sbr in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

I want to disable making *.sbr files in Visual Studio via Solution Settings, because my project has a lot of warnings like:

> BSCMAKE : warning BK4503: minor error in .SBR file 'Foo.sbr' ignored

What are the limitations and disadvantages I get with this?

Comment: No clue about disabling `.sbr` files.  Regarding the warnings, have you done a clean / complete rebuild?  I get those warnings every now and then, sometimes things get a bit stale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SBR files hold *browse information* for individual source files, which `bscmake` then compiles into a BSC file. Visual Studio versions up to 2010 or so used to be able to load a BSC file in the Object Browser, see for example [Using .Bsc Files to Enable Browsing To References of C++ Symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/95ws11cy.aspx). Nowadays, I believe BSC files are still only used by some 3rd party utilities and extensions.

To control SBR generation, follow the steps from [/FR, /Fr (Create .Sbr File)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5a52hhk.aspx):

> To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment
>
> - Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
> - Click the C/C++ folder.
> - Click the **Browse Information** property page.
> - Modify the **Browse Information File** or **Enable Browse Information** property.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 uses these for Code Analysis or something... I can't remember for sure, I just know that I went to use one of the fancy features and it prompted me to enable generation of SBR files.  Which is why I'm here trying to turn them off again :)

Comment: @Orwellophile It would be interesting to know what that feature was, and whether it was a VS builtin vs. a 3rd party extension. The [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/bscmake-reference) say that "*BSCMAKE ... is no longer used by the IDE ... Certain third-party tools use .bsc files for code analysis*".

Answer (score 0):

dxiv's point is right. However, one may also need to check the Browse Information -> General settings.

Comment: this would be better as a comment to dxiv's answer as it is not a full answer.

Comment: Totally agree, it's just I'm not allowed to put comments, as my points are below 50 :) that's why added as an answer

Answer (score 0):

In VS solution explore, right click the project. In property page[I am in VS2013]:
1. select 'Configuration Properties'-'C/C++'-'Browse Information';
2. in right dialog, select 'NO' in 'Enable Browse Information' ComboBox;
3. select 'OK'